# Why does Anderson-Darling statistic increase as Frequency is increased for my data?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, lognormal-distribution, minitab, anderson-darling-test

I have been carrying out [sieve analysis](https://uta.pressbooks.pub/soilmechanics/chapter/sieve-analysis/) to estimate the median particle size of a powder. I wanted to check if the data so far followed a normal or lognormal distribution, as I have come across resources on sieve analysis that use exp(mu) to find the median. I have been recording the percentage mass of the powder in each interval.

For my frequency I tried using the average percentage mass per interval. Minitab rejected the percentages as invalid data, so instead I multiplied the percentages by different multiples of 10 and treated the new values as counts. I found that every time I multiplied by 10, the Anderson-Darling statistic also increased by a multiple of 10. Why is this? Also, can I get Minitab to accept these percentages as frequency without causing this increase in the A-D statistic? See the pictures below for context, (In the picture with the values, Opening Size refers to the diameter of the gaps in the mesh, i.e on average 0.767% of the particles have a diameter greater than 2000 micrometers. Also the last ln(C1) is only there so I can have a data point to graph for diameter less than 180 micrometers).

[image: Percentages x 10]

[image: Percentages x 1000]

[image: Percentages x 100000]

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain how "frequency" is reflected in any of your graphs or tables?

Comment: The issue is I can only measure how the mass is distributed between the sieves. I thought by multiplying the percentages by multiples of 10 I could use the results as fake frequencies. So instead of saying 32.850% of the mass is between 1000 and 710 micrometers, I could say that from 10,000 trials of an experiment, I recorded the outcome "710" 3,285 times. Is this something I can do?

Comment: Although you can do it, as you have discovered, it is meaningless.  You are, in effect, manufacturing data by telling the test you have far more observations than you actually do.  If all you have are the binned *counts* (not mere proportions!), then consider using a chi-squared test.

Comment: Ok thank you. Can I ask why you recommend chi-squared? What can I discover about my data?

Comment: The nature of your data remains unclear.  Since this is a sieve analysis, I would expect you to measure *total mass* per interval, rather than any kind of percentage or count.  But since you refer to some kind of "average," this suggests you might have performed a set of such measurements for multiple samples. That raises important questions about what your data really are and what kinds of inferences you want to make.  Consider editing your post to include that information.